# how to execute jQuery code when route is visited?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have an off-canvas menu that gets drawn in once a Vue route is clicked using jQuery, like so:

```
$('.order-drawer').show();
$('body').toggleClass( 'order-drawer-open' );
```

My route is very simple and is displayed as follows:

```
<router-link to="/order" exact class="order-drawer-toggler">
    <a>Order Now</a>
</router-link>

<router-view></router-view>
```

Now, how can I make sure that when http://test.dev/test/#/order is viewed in the browser, that then my jQuery calls are getting executed? How can I call a function onload of a route view?

Edit:
My routes file looks as follows:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/order',
        component: require('./views/Order.vue')
    }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

Comment: What component is rendered at /order?  You would do it in the `mounted()` hook of that component, although mixing jQuery and Vue might be a bit counterproductive, since it would be vastly better to let Vue drive the interaction.

Comment: check the [vuejs lifecycle hooks](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks)

Comment: @DavidL I am rather new to Vue and was planning on driving the interaction with it, but I have to manipulate the body-tag to add some css transitions when the drawer pulls in from the side. I found no way of doing so via Vue. I updated my question with my routes file

Comment: @AmrAly I have used mounted(), created() etc. before, but not in a sense of when it comes to implementing it when a route is viewed. How can I trigger such specific to one route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allow your routing to drive your component and in that component, drive the jQuery behavior.

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/order',
        component: require('./views/Order.vue')
    }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

Order.vue

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        $('.order-drawer').show();
        $('body').toggleClass( 'order-drawer-open' );
    }
}
```

When the component is created and mounted, it will show the drawer.  There is nothing more you need to do.  When `vue-router` routes TO the route, it will create and mount the component and your jQuery functions will be called.

Comment: Thanks! I feel embarrassed even for asking this now that I see a solution. I was looking at a completely different direction. Thanks so much again!

Comment: @Chris no need to feel embarrassed!  State-based routing is a different way of reasoning about your applications and requires a bit of a mindset change.  Happy to help!